# Why clearInterval doesn't work on a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect, node.js-client

this is the code

```
var t = ()=>{

    setInterval(()=>{

        console.log('hello')

    },1000)


}

t();

clearInterval(t)
```

Why the clearinterval does not block execution of the setInterval?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work on a function because that's just now how the mechanism was designed. Calls to `setInterval()` return a number that acts as an identifier for the timer that the call establishes. That number is what has to be passed to `clearInterval()`.

It doesn't cause an error to pass something that's not a number, or to pass a number that doesn't identify an active timer, but the call has no effect.

In your case, your `t()` function could simply return the result of the `setInterval()` call, and your  outer code can save that for use later however you like.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you need to return the id of the interval and clear that id.

According to the documentation:

> setInterval returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the
>   interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().

```js
//function that keeps logging 'hello' on the console
var t = ()=>{
    //return the id of the interval
    return setInterval(()=>{
        console.log('hello')
    },1000)

}

//get the id of the interval created by the "t" function
var id = t();
//alerts the id just to see it
alert(id);
//clear it - function will stop executing
clearInterval(id);
```

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

because you should clearInterval on reference for setInterval().

```
var interval = setInterval();
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

T is not equal to the setInterval returned value as you don't return a value from your arrow function, and don't assign it to a value.

Try this snippet instead:

```
var t = ()=>
    setInterval(()=>{
        console.log('hello')
    },1000)

var interval = t();
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let intervalId = null;

cycle(true);

function cycle(r) {

    let myInterval = () => {

        return setInterval(() => plusSlides(1), 1000);
    }

    if (!r) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      
    } else {
        intervalId = myInterval();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding an explanation as to how this code snippet answers the question.