# Can't use clearInterval() method

Tags: javascript

It probably has to do with the 'timer' scope, but I can't get where is the problem. If anyone knows :)

```
function startTimer() {

    let time = 0;
    progress.style.width = time + '%';

    let timer = function() {

        setInterval(function() {

            time += 0.5;
            progress.style.width = time + '%';
            if (time >= 100) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    timer();
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the argument returned by `setInterval`  to `clearInterval`. You are just passing a random function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why clearInterval doesn't work on a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240154/why-clearinterval-doesnt-work-on-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the instance of `setInterval()` in order to clear it. You are passing a function into `clearInterval()`

```
function startTimer() {

    let time = 0;
    progress.style.width = time + '%';
    // declare instance variable
    let intervalTimer;

    let timer = function() {
         // assign instance
         intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {

            time += 0.5;
            progress.style.width = time + '%';
            if (time >= 100) {
                // clear instance
                clearInterval( intervalTimer);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    timer();
}
```

Comment: Just a nit-pick, `setInterval`doesn't return an instance, it returns an id of that particular instance which is an integer. (not my down vote, though).

Comment: @Teemu right...just didn't want to get into a long winded explanation of what it actually returned

Comment: Well, a long explanation is better than a misleading answer ..?

Comment: @Teemu what is so misleading? The fact that it returns an id is still instance specific

Answer (score 0):

`const delay = 300 // time in ms
const intervalId = window.setInterval(()=>{ // do stuff here }, delay)`

later

`window.clearInterval(intervalId)`